# Converting image identified by PyTesseract to an array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, image-processing, python-tesseract

I have an image with a list of numbers which I have scanned using PyTesseract to construct a string. Concretely, here is the code:

```py
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\\\Program Files\\\Tesseract-OCR\\\tesseract.exe'

str1=pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('D:/Image.png'))
```

Here's the image I am scanning:

[image]

The problem is that PyTesseract is scanning the image as individual characters instead of integers.

I would like to understand why this is happening and what can I do to get the desired result.

In short, PyTesseract is not scanning integers in a list of numbers, instead scanning them as individual characters. How do I tell it to scan for integers and put them in an array?

Comment: Did you mean that it will return you a string instead of a list of number?

Comment: It returns a string of strings. I need a string of numbers.

Comment: What?So you want to convert it to `list`?`I need a string of numbers. `Could you edit your post and add your expectation output to your post?

Comment: A list of numbers would be fine. Okay, let me edit as to what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,If you only want to get a list,Use `re.split` and `strip` can solve it.(Because tesseract's result has some errors).

You can try this:

```
import pytesseract
import re

data = pytesseract.image_to_string('OCR.png')
dataList = re.split(r',|\.| ',data) # split the string
resultList = [int(i.strip()) for i in dataList if i != ''] # remove the '' str and convert str to int.
print(resultList)

# result: [71, 194, 38, 1701, 89, 76, 11, 83, 1629, 48, 94, 63, 132, 16, 111, 95, 84, 341, 975, 14, 40, 64, .......
```

Comment: Beautiful, that worked perfectly ! That split command escaped me...